# Can someone explain MVC model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a model which I create and pass to my view. The model creates a form and using the `HttpPost` attribute I get the model back. I save the model to the database and then I would like to return a default model state to the view (IE drop down values, but not the selected items)

I created an empty model, passed this to the view, but the values remain the same and I dont understand why.

My View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h2>Configuration settings</h2>
      </legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceType)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeviceTypeSelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.DeviceType, "Value", "Text"),new {@class = "DeviceTypeDDL"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceTypeSelectedItem)
      </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfigGroup)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ConfigGroupSelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.ConfigGroup, "Value", "Text"),new {@class = "ConfigGroupDDL"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfigGroupSelectedItem)
      </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfigName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ConfigNameSelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.ConfigName, "Value", "Text"),new {@class = "ConfigNameDDL"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfigNameSelectedItem)
      </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfigValue)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfigValue)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfigValue)
      </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MergeOrDelete)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.MergeOrDelete, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "MergeDeleteDDL" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem)
      </div>

      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ManagementGroupId)

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
      var model = CreateDefaultConfigModel(id);
      return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(vmConfiguration model)
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        bool isMerge = model.MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem == 1 ? true : false;
        _configLogic.AddConfigurationValue((int)model.ConfigNameSelectedItem, (int)model.ManagementGroupId, model.ConfigValue, isMerge);
        return View(CreateDefaultConfigModel(model.ManagementGroupId));
      }
      else
      {
        return View(model);
      }
    }
private vmConfiguration CreateDefaultConfigModel(int id)
{
  var model = new vmConfiguration
  {
    DeviceType = _configLogic.GetDevices,
    ConfigGroup = new List<SelectListItem>() { EmptySelect() },
    ConfigName = new List<SelectListItem>() { EmptySelect() },
    ConfigGroupSelectedItem = null,
    MergeOrDeleteSelectedItem = null,
    DeviceTypeSelectedItem = null,
    ConfigNameSelectedItem = null,
    ManagementGroupId = id,
    ParamData = _configLogic.GetParamValuesForGroup(id)
  };
  return model;
}
private static SelectListItem EmptySelect()
{
  return new SelectListItem { Text = "No value", Value = "-1" };
}
private ConfigurationLogic _configLogic;
```

Doing research I've found that If I call `this.ModelState.Clear();` before creating the new model then it works, but why does MVC ignore the model Ive passed and use the bound one?

Comment: Is the model valid and do that values get updated as expected?

Comment: Hi chris, yes everything is valid, everything works and there are no errors. The issue is what I expected to happen didnt and i wanna know why.

Comment: This looks fine to me, are you sure the else statement isn't being ran via the debugger? Because that's what I would assume is happening. You mention "no errors" but ModelState errors aren't raised as exceptions.

Comment: Hi graham, debugging through it takes the logical path I'd expect. There are no model errors. I pass an empty model, but it binds to the previous anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
return View(CreateDefaultConfigModel(model.ManagementGroupId));
```

to this

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ManagementGroupId });
```

It's not ignoring your model, it's attempting to fill out your form when you send them back to the same Index page because it assumes you're sending them back due to requiring more information and it's trying to be helpful by not forcing the user to re-enter all the information again. This info is all stored in ModelState as it holds the attempted values that were posted back to the server. Redirecting after a successful post is the recommended pattern anyway. Lookup the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Thanks Yarx, that's the answer i was looking for.